# $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is closed if and only if $V$ is a union of closed balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I've proved that $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open if and only if $V=\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in A}B_\alpha$, where $B_\alpha$ is an open ball. Now I'm asked the following question:

> What happens to this result when *open* is replaced by *closed*?

My answer is that this result will hold for closed sets as well, but in order to prove it, we must take points $\vec{x}\in V-∂V$, that is, not include any points on the boundary. We take these points and show that a closed ball $B_{r_{\vec{x}}}(\vec{x})$ is in the union of closed balls, etc.

But is my point valid?

Comment: so a point is not closed ?, what about a line in $R^2$?

Comment: Only a _finite_ union of closed sets is closed

Comment: @TsemoAristide A point _is_ a closed ball with radius $0$. But you're right for the line.

Comment: @TsemoAristide If a point is a closed ball, then every set is a union of closed balls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result becomes false when "open" is replaced by "closed". Take $n=1$, and let $B_k$ be the closed ball around $0$ of radius $k/(k+1)$, so $B_k = [-\frac k{k+1}, \frac k {k+1}]$.  Then $\bigcup_k B_k = (-1,1)$ is not closed.

The $\Rightarrow$ direction is true, in a somewhat trivial way: for a closed set $C$, $C = \bigcup_{x\in C} \{x\} = \bigcup_{x\in C}\mathcal{B}(x; 0)$, where $\mathcal{B}(x; \delta)$ is the closed ball of radius $\delta$ around $x$, because $\mathcal{B}(x; 0) = \{x\}$. (Some infinite unions of closed sets *are* closed.)

The example above shows that the $\Leftarrow$ direction is in general false (though it's true for finite unions).

Comment: As @Hippalectryon mentioned in the comments above, it appears that the result is not false for a finite union of balls.

Comment: @sequence It's hard to fit finiteness into either direction of the "iff", however.

Comment: BrianO: why is it hard to fit finiteness into the "iff"? I'm quite new to topology.

Comment: @sequence There are closed sets which aren't the union of finitely many closed balls: $[0, 1/2] \cup [1, 3/2] \cup ... \cup [n, n +\frac 1 2] \cup ...$ is the complement of an open set so it's closed, but it isn't a union of finitely many closed balls. So you can't just add "finitely many" the the righthand side of the *iff*.

Comment: So I guess one has to stipulate the condition "given that $V$ can be represented as a union of finitely many closed balls..." in order for this to hold true.

Comment: That would make for a fairly trivial theorem, though: "If $V$ is a finite union of closed balls, then [$V$ is closed *iff* $V$ is a union of closed balls]" doesn't have much power. From the hypothesis, $V$ is closed, so ($\Rightarrow$) is just "$V$ is a union of closed balls", which of course follows. Similarly, ($\Leftarrow$) becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the fact that $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$ need not be open for a collection of open sets $\{U_n\}$. So if $\{U_n\}$ is a collection of open sets such that $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$ = $C$ for some closed set $C$, what happens when we look at the complements? You can take the complement of the sets $B_k = [-\frac k{k+1}, \frac k {k+1}]$ mentioned above if you want a concrete example of a suitable collection $\{U_n\}$.